# why the @track Value is not updating in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am new to LWC. I created the first LWC successfully but the problem is that when is change the `@track name =' Helllo'` to `@track name =' Helllo world'` in the js file and deploy the LWC after that I reload the page but the value still not updated. why?

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="HelloWorld" icon-name="custom:custom14">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <p> {name}</p>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```
import { LightningElement,api,track } from 'lwc';

export default class HelloWorld extends LightningElement {

    @track name ='Hello World ';

}
```

Comment: Please stop adding irrelevant tags (this has nothing to do with Salesforce DX)

Comment: Have you done a hard refresh? (CTRL + F5)

Comment: CTRL+F5? How to do this?

Comment: You can disable caching: Setup > Session Settings > Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance

Comment: To add to Ruben's point, your browser is likely to be keeping a local cached copy of the earlier version as part of the normal performance optimisation. But when developing, turn that off per Ruben's instructions, as you want the changed file not a cached file.

Answer (score 1):

@track is no longer necessary for simple variables (non-objects), and in addition, it has nothing to do with why the display value isn't changing. Make sure you're logged in to the right org, viewing the right page/component/whatever, your code has successfully deployed, and clearing your cache (Ctrl+Shift+Del on most browsers).